# How I can keep and restore JMSservers to their last known state after a reboot

Tags: jms, weblogic, message-queue, oracle-fusion-middleware, consumption

I am trying to find if there is any parameter which will keep the Consumption Parameters as the previous workable state after a full restart of Weblogic Server.

I would like to restore JMSservers to their last known state after a reboot-restart.

I have tested and i have enabled the ConsumptionPaused to true in a JMSServer via wlst and I have done a full restart but after the restarting the ConsumptionPaused has changed to false.

Please for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found that with the parameter ConsumptionPausedAtStartup enabled, after the restart of Weblogic then **all the osb resources under the destination of JMSServer will have the ConsumptionPaused as true in JMS Queue layer level and not in JMS Server layer.**

If you will not disabled the parameter ConsumptionPausedAtStartup, then every time you will restart the server then all the queues under this JMSServer will be with ConsumptionPaused as true.

Best Regards,
Nickname

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using the setConsumptionPausedAtStartup method on the JMSServerMBean mbean

Comment: Finally, i have found this parameter and i have tried the below scenario : I have enabled via wlst the ConsumptionPaused as true and with the above parameter the ConsumptionPausedAtStartup also as true and i have restart the managed server. After the restarting the ConsumptionPausedAtStartup is true  (as expected) but the ConsumptionPaused as false (not as expected).

Comment: I think the ConsumptionPaused parameter will always be false at startup. If you need to prevent jms destination from consuming messages at startup set ConsumptionPausedAtStartup to true

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer and your interesting also. As I have described above, I have set the parameter ConsumptionPausedAtStartup to true and the ConsumptionPaused as true too, but after the restart as you have said the ConsumptionPaused parameter has returned to false and the ConsumptionPausedAtStartup have still be true. My question now is why since the ConsumptionPausedAtStartup has set as true(still after restart) after the restart the messages were consumed by the queues.

Comment: ok, it seems not to work as we think. Maybe a bug. Which WLS version are you using ?